# Custom cargo command introduces spurious first argument when run with cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm building a little tool called `cargo-latest` which you can call like `cargo-latest git2 serde anyhow` to get the latest versions of those crates. Cargo has this nifty feature where if your binary starts with `cargo-something` it will just pretend like it's a built in cargo command, so you can call it as `cargo something`.

Unfortunately, when it does this it does not strip the second word out of the argument list, so `std::env::args()` looks like `["/path/to/cargo-latest", "latest", "git2", "serde", "anyhow"]`. I could get around this by skipping the first argument, but then that breaks if I call it directly with `cargo-latest anyhow` (it would skip `anyhow`). I could do a check to see if the second argument is `latest`, but there is actually a crate named `latest`, so that would break if I ever wanted to do `cargo-latest latest`.

I'm wondering if this might be a bug. I can't think of a good way around it other than checking if the second argument is `latest` and skipping it, which obviously isn't ideal, but I guess is preferable to having it show the latest version of the `latest` crate every time I run it with `cargo latest`.

Can anyone think of a good way around this?

**Edit:** I submitted a bug report about this [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/9373).

Comment: Upon investigation I found the popular [cargo-edit](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-edit) commands *require* the spurious argument.

Comment: I suppose a dirty option is to add a flag for when you are invoking it from the command line: `cargo-latest -x latest`.